# Code working in PyCharm but not when the .py file is run

Tags: python, json, pycharm

I am trying to load a JSON file into python with the following code:

```
import json


def find_case(tag):
    with open("C:\\Users\\brend\\Documents\\File Organiser\\Files\\.filepaths\\" + tag + ".json", "r") as f:
        filepaths_dict = json.load(f)
```

This seems to work fine withing PyCharm but crashes immediately on the above line. Can anyone tell me what is causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Please add more of your code. Especially the entry and the part calling the function.

Comment: All that is, is a function definition. Nothing is being executed. Is there an error msg for the function definition?

Comment: Without more information (e.g. the error from Python) it is impossible to answer properly. But I suspect that in PyCharm you are using a different environment (either different python or different virtual environment. An other unrelated comment: you are using Windows, so it is really better to explicitly specify the encoding. [Windows is the only remaining place where encoding is just the user defined one, and not a fix encoding (and not utf-8)]